# Filter child elements in an ASP.NET Linq-to-Entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following type of situation:

```
TABLE Customers (
    CustomerID int,
    etc... )

TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int,
    CustomerID int,
    Active bit,
    etc... )
```

I am using this in an ASP.NET MVC web application using Linq-to-Entities.  I want to select all Customers and populate the Customer.Orders navigational property, and should only be populated with orders where `Active==true`.

I've seen other questions that point to `DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith`, but it appears I can't use that in ASP.NET.  I've also seen [this article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/aspnet/how-to/3908044/sorting-child-collections.aspx), but it appears I would need to be calling CreateSourceQuery() in my view as I enumerate through Customers.  This is possible, I suppose, but seems to be breaking MVC paradigm.

This seems to be a similar situation to "[Filter child collection using a child collection of the child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503876/filter-child-collection-using-a-child-collection-of-the-child)" except I need a solution for Linq-to-Entities instead of NHibernate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer [in this tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx).