# Domain Driven Design: Aggregate roots with large collections

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I was wondering how I would handle aggregate roots that contain collections with a lot of entities.

Like:

```
public class AggregateRoot
{
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } // 10.000 entities
}
```

How would I query the child collection to get specific children? I am using Nhibernate btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Nhibernate's [collection filters](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/04/nhibernate-filters.aspx) for this, see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247571/filter-child-collection-returned-with-aggregate-root-using-nhibernate) for examples.

Comment: And this should be implemented in the Repository ( aggregateRootRepository.getChildren(0, 100) ).

Comment: @Kdeveloper: Yes, that's the general idea. Although when situations like this come up, you need to ask yourself "Am I missing the real aggregate root?"